# Task running is failed with "make" in custom task (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: makefile, visual-studio-code

I used Visual Studio Code 0.10.2. When I tried to run task using GNU make command, the task is failed with error messages like below. My GNU make is obtained from MSYS2 x64 (http://msys2.github.io/) and my system environment is Windows 10 Education x64.

```
make -C 00.BootLoader
  0 [main] make 24552 D:\GNU\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
192 [main] make 24552 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
  0 [main] make 23968 fork: child -1 - forked process 24552 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
```

But when I tried same command using console window (cmd.exe), "make" works successfully. How to fix this?

Comment: When I tried to use MSYS2 x86, it works without any errors. Does Visual Studio Code not support running x64 application as task? But Python x64 works without any error in task... What is the problem?

Comment: Similar: [NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 cannot build C++ programs after Windows 10 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37892056/55075)