# NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 cannot build C++ programs after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin, fork

My Windows 7 was upgraded to Windows 10 a week ago. Before the upgrade, my NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 with C/C++ plugin worked fine with C++ programs. However, after the Windows 10 upgrade, it cannot build/make C++ programs any more, with the error message below. Note that the Java plugin still works fine, and the C++ editor part is still OK too. The C/C++ Tool Collection is 64-bit Cygwin.

Any clue on what caused this specifically, and any solution on fixing this?

```
===== Complete Error Message Below: ===== 

4 [main] make 5900 C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487 

15248 [main] make 5900 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump 

9 [main] make 4464 fork: child -1 - forked process 5900 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11 

make: nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk:33: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable 

43162 [main] make 2164 C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487 

43898 [main] make 2164 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump 

3943868 [main] make 4464 fork: child -1 - forked process 2164 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11 

make: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable 

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 9s)
```

Comment: Did you do research?  Plenty of links [here](https://www.google.com/#q=fatal+error+in+forked+process+-+fork:+can%27t+reserve+memory+for+parent+stack+0x600000+-+0x800000])

Comment: Paul, thanks for the link.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the links! Yes, I was doing some research on this question these days. Earlier today, also looked at NetBeans "Defining Your C/C++ Project's Development Environment"
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/development-environment.html. Now, going through the links again as you pointed, I got a clue from one of them to solve the problem! The solution was to add the Cygwin32 Tool Collection under NetBeans/Tools/Options/Build Tools, and then use it to build C++ projects. It works!

Comment: The clue was from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249511/git-fails-from-intellij-on-windows-10-with-fork-cant-reserve-memory-for-parent: "... you can't currently fork a 64bit process from a 32bit client". :) Thanks again!